# Erro ao rodar Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-6

Estou começando os meus estudo no EF, seguindo esse [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gs9FaIyba28), fiz até 22 min do vídeo, daí quando vou rodar estoura esse erro:

> System.TypeInitializationException: 'O inicializador de tipo de 'System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig' acionou uma exceção.'
>
> ConfigurationErrorsException: O sistema de configuração falhou ao inicializar
>
> ConfigurationErrorsException: Elemento não reconhecido. (C:\Users\Leandro\source\repos\EntityFw\UIConsole\bin\Debug\UIConsole.exe.Config line 4)

Versão do EF: 6.2.0
Versão do dotnet: 2.1.503
Visual Studio 2017

Program.cs:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace UIConsole
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // o erro está estourando nessa linha
        DBProduto banco = new DBProduto();

        Produto produto01 = new Produto();
        produto01.ID = 1;
        produto01.Nome = "Arroz";

        banco.Produtos.Add(produto01);
        banco.SaveChanges();

        IEnumerable<Produto> produtosNoDB = banco.Produtos.ToList();

        Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", produtosNoDB.First().ID, produtosNoDB.First().Nome);

        Console.ReadKey();
     }
   }
 }
```

Produto.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace UIConsole
 {
   public class Produto
    {
      public int ID { get; set; }
      public string Nome { get; set; }
    }
  }
```

DBProduto.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Text;

namespace UIConsole
{
    public class DBProduto : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Produto> Produtos { get; set; }
    }
}
```

App.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
      <add name="DBProduto" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=DBProduto"
       providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    </connectionStrings>
  </configSections>
  <startup> 
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seu erro está no `app.config`. Coloque o elemento `connectionString` dentro de `configuration`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
  </startup>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DBProduto" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=DBProduto"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```